# 4.24 Motion controllers no longer work after updating from 4.21

Tags: c++, input, unreal-engine4, virtual-reality

I recently updated my VR C++ project from 4.21 to 4.24 and GetComponentLocation() no longer works.

```
USceneComponent::GetComponentLocation()
```

Did this change recently?

This is what my hand blueprint(s) look like:
[image]

Here is what my code looks like for spawning and attaching the hand blueprints:
[image]

This is the code for getting the location of the motion controller:
[image]

Edit: bump

Comment: Does this help?: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steamvr_unreal_plugin/issues/110

Comment: @afghanimah Thanks, but I tried it and still no luck.

Comment: Don't post code as images; post it as text.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out, I needed to set the owner of the spawned hands, here is the solution:

[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.